# Automatic Findings - RSA Archer

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

Can someone help me determine where to enable automatic findings generation for a questionnaire in RSA Archer GRC version 6.3?

Answer (score 1):

When you select your questionnaire from the application builder page, it’ll be under the properties tab, then there will be a secondary tab set where you’ll find the findings tab. On that tab, there is a checkbox to enable automatic generation of findings, along with the criteria under which to generate findings.